# Caracteres 'estranhos' no MySQL

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um *site dinâmico* e em uma das `forms` de cadastro um usuario foi gravado assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código php da página:**

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$btnCadUsuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadUsuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadUsuario){
    include_once 'conexao.php';
    $dados_rc = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $erro = false;

    $dados_st = array_map('strip_tags', $dados_rc);
    $dados = array_map('trim', $dados_st);

    if(in_array('',$dados)){
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Necessário preencher todos os campos";
    }elseif((strlen($dados['senha'])) < 6){
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "A senha deve ter no minímo 6 caracteres";
    }elseif(stristr($dados['senha'], "'")) {
        $erro = true;
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Caracter ( ' ) utilizado na senha é inválido";
    }else{
        $result_usuario = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE usuario='". $dados['usuario'] ."'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
            $erro = true;
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Este usuário já está sendo utilizado";
        }

        $result_usuario = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='". $dados['email'] ."'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
            $erro = true;
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Este e-mail já está cadastrado";
        }
    }


    //var_dump($dados);
    if(!$erro){
        //var_dump($dados);
        $dados['senha'] = password_hash($dados['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO users (nome, email, usuario, senha) VALUES (
                        '" .$dados['nome']. "',
                        '" .$dados['email']. "',
                        '" .$dados['usuario']. "',
                        '" .$dados['senha']. "'
                        )";
        $resultado_usario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
        if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
            $_SESSION['msgcad'] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";
            header("Location: login.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Erro ao cadastrar o usuário";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Tenho muita dificuldade em utilizar essa ferramenta aqui. Segue alternativa no [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/adijukemog.xml).

Após realizar um input utilizando acento e fontes especiais tipo     foi gravado o seguinte:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Alguma falha no código pode ter enviado esses caracteres?
- O *usuário* tentou algum tipo de injecção/crack no meu site?
- Estes caracteres são prejudiciais?
- Se sim, quais medidas devo tomar?

Comment: Ou talvez não seja duplicata? Ao ler novamente fiquei na dúvida... As perguntas contidas aqui no final do texto não visam sanar o problema, apenas entendê-lo e seu impacto na experiência do usuário

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado se o problema for a codificação é duplicata. Mas esta me parecendo que não é isso, então vou esperar o Lucas confirmar para que eu possa remover meu voto de duplicata.

Comment: Lucas isso ocorre com frequência? Cada vez que você cadastra valores como `èéóúçñ`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Vou simular um cadastro utilizando acentos para detectar se o problema é o encoding.

Comment: @gato dentre 20 cadastros este foi o único que  apresentou esses caracteres.

Comment: Mas consegues gravar carácteres com acento?

Comment: Informaçoes adicionadas.

Comment: tente fazer com que sua senha grave somente caracteres ou numeros, as vezes pode ter sido algum carácter especial ou acentuação mesmo

Comment: Lucas tente depurar assim `$dados_rc = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);` ficará assim `var_dump($dados_rc);`